# Why do you need timeout in milliseconds and Why do I have to declare 2 Classes with separate run () methods for separate blocks

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, synchronized

Im having issue with understanding some background things going on in my multithreaded application.

**My question number 1:**

I have a class (called *SyncClass*) which is responsible for creating synchronized blocks within 2 instance methods, called *test1()* and *test2()*. The *test1()* is supposed to increment an integer by 1 and then print it out and *test2()* which is supposed to do the same thing. These methods are supposed to increment the integer as long as the value is smaller than 10. So basically when *test1()* has incremented the value with 1, then it should hand it over to the other method *test2()* which should do the same thing until the condition is met.

At the moment these *2* methods have wait(2000), because if I have a simple wait with no limit then the program just keep executing with only partial result printed to the screen and then it just hangs.

There must probably be a better wait to solve it without needing the timeout, or ?

**My question number 2:**

I have an external class (called *TheRunner*) with another member class (called *InnerRunner*) where both implement Runnable where the outer class is having run()-method to run the test1()-method and the inner class to run the test2()-method.

Is there no way that I can have only one class implementing the Runnable to run the both test1() and test2() methods inside it (i.e. inside the run()-method)?

The code for the SyncClass looks like below:

```
package test;

public class SyncClass {

    int i = 0;
    boolean b = true;

    public void test1() {
        synchronized (this) {
            while((b == true) && (i < 10)) {
                i++;
                System.out.println("test 1:");
                System.out.println(i);
                b = false;

                try {
                    wait(2000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

    }



    public void test2() {
        synchronized (this) {
            while((b == false) && (i < 10)) {
                i++;
                System.out.println("test 2:");
                System.out.println(i);
                b = true;

                try {
                    wait(2000);
                    notify();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }
    }


}
```

And then I have the other class which is implementing Runnable's to run the above methods:

```
package test;

public class TheRunner implements Runnable {

    SyncClass sync;

    public TheRunner(SyncClass sync) {
        this.sync = sync;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        sync.test1();

    }



class InnerRunner implements Runnable{


    SyncClass sync;

    public InnerRunner(SyncClass sync) {
        this.sync = sync;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        sync.test2();
    }


}   


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        SyncClass sync = new SyncClass();
        TheRunner runner = new TheRunner(sync);
        TheRunner.InnerRunner innerRunner = runner.new InnerRunner(sync);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(runner);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(innerRunner);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();



    }
}
```

If I remove the wait(2000) and replaces it with simple wait() then the output will be only:

test1:
1

test2:
2

..but it should continue up to 10, i.e. next iteration should be test1: 3, test2: 4, etc which it does when I change it with wait(2000). I dont really understand this?

Comment: Please, one question per post.

Comment: I thought about putting in one post since they are kind of interconnected to each other.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot of code, with a lot of misconceptions. I've simplified this example and it does not require timeouts or passing a value to `wait`. What you should use in a real code, is an `AtomicInteger` but here I've used an `int[]` so you can hopefully understand what is going on. Whenever you `wait` you need to ensure that some form of `notify` is invoked. Let's start with a ***single*** `Runnable` I've named `Counter`. Like,

```
public class Counter implements Runnable {
    private static int[] ai = { 0 };
    private int threadId;

    public Counter(int threadId) {
        this.threadId = threadId;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (ai) {
            int v;
            while ((v = ai[0]) < 10) {
                if (v % 2 != threadId % 2) {
                    System.out.printf("%s test%d %d%n", 
                            Thread.currentThread().getName(), 
                            threadId, ai[0]++);
                    ai.notifyAll();
                } else {
                    System.out.printf("%s test%d wait%n", 
                            Thread.currentThread().getName(), threadId);
                    try {
                        ai.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We can then test it (the `join`(s) aren't strictly necessary, but I like to wait for the code to complete) like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Counter(1));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Counter(2));
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    try {
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

which should (consistently) result in

```
Thread-0 test1 0
Thread-0 test1 wait
Thread-1 test2 1
Thread-1 test2 wait
Thread-0 test1 2
Thread-0 test1 wait
Thread-1 test2 3
Thread-1 test2 wait
Thread-0 test1 4
Thread-0 test1 wait
Thread-1 test2 5
Thread-1 test2 wait
Thread-0 test1 6
Thread-0 test1 wait
Thread-1 test2 7
Thread-1 test2 wait
Thread-0 test1 8
Thread-0 test1 wait
Thread-1 test2 9
```

Comment: Could you explain to me why my code works with the timeout passed into the wait()? ..i.e. printing all the elements as opposed to not having the timeout?

Comment: Because nothing ever notifies them, they wait until the timeout expires. Simple as that.